# What means the notation $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)<1$ for a real function $f$ with infinite singularities?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, infinity, singularity

Let $f$ be a real function which possesses an infinite set (of points) of singularities. I think about, for example to
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)},$$
but just to give an example.

During the calculus class today we discussed about if it possible for a real function with an infinite set of points of singularities to be below a positive constant $c$ (to fox the ideas, we can say below $1$). Someone said that it would be enough to ask that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)<1$.

Actually I am not convinced about that because what prevents that $f$ has a singularity at infinity? I mean, about the example I wrote above, what does mean "$x\to +\infty$"?
Do you have in mind any examples of real function with infinite singularities for which makes sense the writing "$x\to +\infty$" instead?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly it is not true that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ exists; in particular the usual definition is that if the limit $L$ exists, then we must have for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is some bound $M$ such that $x > M \implies \left|\frac{1}{\cos(x)} - L\right| < \epsilon$. Since $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ takes on every value outside of $(-1, 1)$ on every interval $[x, x + 2\pi)$, this can't happen.

The issue is that one needs the set of singularities to be bounded; in particular consider a function like
$$
f(x) = \frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sin(x^{-1})}
$$

Away from $[-1, 1]$, this function is well defined, but it certainly has infinite singularities at $\pm (\pi n)^{-1}$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$. And yet we see that as $x \to \pm \infty$, $f(x) \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What do you mean saying that it is well defined away from $[-1, 1]$?

Comment: @C.Bishop: in this particular case that means, that it is defined at every point, is finite at every point and it bounded on that set. As an example, $\frac1x$ is not well define on say $[-2, 5]$ since it's not defined at $0$.

Comment: @Ilya thank you for the comment. Could you please help to "traduce" in formal mathematical language the requirement on $f$ to have a (infinite) set of singularities which is bounded? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let's call a singularity $s \in \mathbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ of $f$ any point where $\lim_{x \to s} f(x)$ doesn't exist (including when the limit is infinite). In particular under this definition, what I mean by bounded is that if $S = \{ s \mid f \text{ has a singularity at } s\}$, we need that there is some bound such that $s < M$ for any $s \in S$, if we are asking for the limit at $+ \infty$. It's not hard to see that if no such bound exists, then the limit at $+\infty$ is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the epsilon-delta definition of a limit at infinity is that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find $M$ such that $x > M \implies |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$. Since it has to hold for any positive $\varepsilon$, it has to hold for any value we could choose, for example if $\varepsilon = 1$ then there has to be a point where $|f(x) - 1| < 1$ for all $x > M$, which implies $0 < f(x) < 1$.

So if $f(x)$ has any essential singularities, they have to be bounded away from $+\infty$, i.e. they must all exist at points $x < M$. Which is fine - you can create a function with infinitely many singularities in the interval $(-\infty, M)$, as long as it then behaves nicely after that.